# POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def login(self):
    url = 'https://login.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1'
    data = "locale=en_US&non_com_login=&email="+self.email+"&pass="+self.password+"&lsd=20TOl"
    usock = self.opener.open('http://www.facebook.com')
    usock = self.opener.open(url, data)
    if "Logout" in usock.read():
        print("Logged in.")
    else:
        print("failed login")
        print(usock.read())
        sys.exit()
```

Can you tell me how and were the error is?

POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is a string, but `urllib` requires it to be a `bytes` object since it is being sent in raw form, without encoding information. You have two possibilites to solve this:

Either you convert your string to a bytes object by calling `str.encode`. This, by default, will use UTF8 encoding, so it should work with most servers:

```
usock = self.opener.open(url, data.encode())
```

The other way would be to specify your data in bytes directly. To create byte strings, just prefix the literal by a `b`:

```
data = b"This is some bytes data"
```

Since you are concatenating different things here, the first option is easier as you don’t need to encode every single part of the concatenated string.

Btw. you are calling `opener.open` twice, once without data and once with data. You should probably remove the first call; unless of course you want to collect some initial cookies or something, in which case you should *at least* close the response object again using `usock.close()`.