# Python 3 urllib produces TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, urllib2, urllib

I am trying to convert working Python 2.7 code into Python 3 code and I am receiving a type error from the urllib request module.

I used the inbuilt 2to3 Python tool to convert the below working urllib and urllib2 Python 2.7 code:

```
import urllib2
import urllib

url = "https://www.customdomain.com"
d = dict(parameter1="value1", parameter2="value2")

req = urllib2.Request(url, data=urllib.urlencode(d))
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
resp = f.read()
```

The output from the 2to3 module was the below Python 3 code:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse

url = "https://www.customdomain.com"
d = dict(parameter1="value1", parameter2="value2")

req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=urllib.parse.urlencode(d))
f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
resp = f.read()
```

When the Python 3 code is run the following error is produced:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-206954140899> in <module>()
      5 
      6 req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=urllib.parse.urlencode(d))
----> 7 f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
      8 resp = f.read()

C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    159     else:
    160         opener = _opener
--> 161     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    162 
    163 def install_opener(opener):

C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    459         for processor in self.process_request.get(protocol, []):
    460             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 461             req = meth(req)
    462 
    463         response = self._open(req, data)

C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in do_request_(self, request)
   1110                 msg = "POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. " \
   1111                       "It cannot be of type str."
-> 1112                 raise TypeError(msg)
   1113             if not request.has_header('Content-type'):
   1114                 request.add_unredirected_header(

TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str.
```

I have also read two other tickets ([ticket1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850421/post-data-should-be-bytes-or-an-iterable-of-bytes-it-cannot-be-of-type-str) and [ticket2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440485/typeerror-post-data-should-be-bytes-or-an-iterable-of-bytes-it-cannot-be-str)) which mentioned encoding the date.

When I changed the line `f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)` to `f = urllib.request.urlopen(req.encode('utf-8'))` I received the following error: `AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'encode'`

I am stuck as to how to make the Python 3 code work. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.request.html#urllib-examples) *Note that params output from urlencode is encoded to bytes before it is sent to urlopen as data:*

```
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(d).encode("utf-8")
req = urllib.request.Request(url)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req,data=data) as f:
    resp = f.read()
    print(resp)
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
url = 'https://www.customdomain.com'
d = dict(parameter1="value1", parameter2="value2")

f = urllib.parse.urlencode(d)
f = f.encode('utf-8')

req = urllib.request.Request(url, f)
```

Your problem lies in the way you were handling the dictionary.

Answer (score -2):

I used python requests module with ZOHO CRM API V2. It worked without any issues.
Here is a sample working code with GET request:

```
import json
import requests

# API methods - https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/api-methods.html
# getrecords API Call
module_name = 'Deals'
authtoken = '*****'
api_url = "https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/json/"+module_name+"/getRecords?authtoken="+authtoken+"&scope=crmapi&fromIndex=1&toIndex=2"

# GET Request
request_response = requests.get(
    url=api_url
    )
print(json.dumps(json.loads(request_response.text), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(",", ": ")))
json_response = json.loads(request_response.text)
```