# Why does Python 3 require an iterable of bytes for urllib?

Tags: python, urllib

Using Python 3 now so I had to adjust my code. Just wanted to download those 2 files, in case they do not exist (idea was that I do not have to download them every single time).

```
import urllib.request
if not  os.path.isfile("test.mat"):
    urllib.request.urlopen("http://ufldl.stanford.edu/housenumbers/test_32x32.mat", "test.mat")

if not  os.path.isfile("train.mat"):
    urllib.request.urlopen("http://ufldl.stanford.edu/housenumbers/train_32x32.mat", "train.mat")
```

The error I get is :

```
TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str.
```

Comment: did you [look up the error message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440485/typeerror-post-data-should-be-bytes-or-an-iterable-of-bytes-it-cannot-be-str)? and try out the already existing solutions? Or even [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760728/python-3-urllib-produces-typeerror-post-data-should-be-bytes-or-an-iterable-of)?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243750/download-file-from-web-in-python-3

Comment: I upvoted and change the title, even though I voted it should be closed as a duplicate.  This was to instruct, yet not discourage, the OP.