# Head First Programming Python 3: Twitter Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python 3

I’m a beginner and trying to learn programming. I am using this book Head First Programming by Paul Barry and David Griffiths. **So somewhere in Chapter 3 page 92-98 the book instructs to write a program so that the manager will be sent directly through his Twitter account the prices of the products, or when to buy**.

So here is the code that I used, this is the same ones that is in the book:

```
import urllib.request
import time


def send_to_twitter(msg):
    password_manager = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgr()
    password_manager.add_password("Twitter API",
    "http://twitter.com/statuses", "username", "password")
    http_handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_manager)
    page_opener = urllib.request.build_opener(http_handler)
    urllib.request.install_opener(page_opener)
    params = urllib.parse.urlencode( {'status': msg} )
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen("http://twitter.com/statuses/update.json", params)
    resp.read()
def get_price():
    page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://beans-r-us.appspot.com/prices.html")
    text = page.read().decode("utf8")
    where = text.find('>$')
    start_of_price = where + 2
    end_of_price = start_of_price + 4
    return float(text[start_of_price:end_of_price])
price_now = input("Do you want to see the price now (Y/N)? ")
if price_now == "Y":
    send_to_twitter(get_price())
else:
    price = 99.99
    while price > 4.74:
        time.sleep(900)
        price = get_price()
send_to_twitter("Buy!")
```

In the username and password part I used my own Twitter account but of course I cant show it here.

So what happened after I entered the error is:

```
Do you want to see the price now (Y/N)? Y

   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BEST\Desktop\python\headfirsttrychapter3.5.py", line 24, in <module>
    send_to_twitter(get_price())
  File "C:\Users\BEST\Desktop\python\headfirsttrychapter3.5.py", line 13, in send_to_twitter
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen("http://twitter.com/statuses/update.json", params)
  File "C:\Users\BEST\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\BEST\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
    req = meth(req)
  File "C:\Users\BEST\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1247, in do_request_
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.
```

Why did this happen? And how can I solve this? :( Thanks very much

Comment: By any chance was the code in the book written for Python 2 ?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760728/python-3-urllib-produces-typeerror-post-data-should-be-bytes-or-an-iterable-of

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3 urllib produces TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760728/python-3-urllib-produces-typeerror-post-data-should-be-bytes-or-an-iterable-of)

Comment: @khelwood uhm no it says it uses python 3 :/