# Formatting Urllib Requests to Get Data From a Server

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I am trying to use python to access pull and plot data from a server (ERRDAP if you're interested).
Here is the code that I am trying to use:
    `url = 'https://scoos.org/erddap/tabledap/autoss.csv?query'
    values = {'time>=' : '2016-07-10T00:00:00Z',
    'time<' : '2017-02-10T00:00:00Z', 
    'temperature' : 'temperature', 
    'time' :'time', 
    'temperature_flagPrimary'}
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
    data.encode('utf-8')
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)`

The error message that I get is: "POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str." I think this either has something to do with me trying to request a csv file or improperly using urllib. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check this link out and see if this helps. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760728/python-3-urllib-produces-typeerror-post-data-should-be-bytes-or-an-iterable-of)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I notice that the link creates a dictionary instead of my current way. Is it possible to pass the `time<=` inside the dictionary?

Comment: that i think will depend on the url server how it interprets. Check if the server supports any of the operations like <,>,<=, etc.

Comment: I believe that the server can interpret it. But when I go to actually form the dictionary isn't there a problem with the code? `dict( time<= : ' Properly formated ISO time')`  Won't this return an error message because of the use of <=