# How to fix the str problem with json.dumps please?

Tags: python, json, string, binary

*Hello, could someone helps me with this please?*

## TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It can not be of type str.

```
import json
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen

postdata = {
    'datetime': str(calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())),
    'sensorId': "1",
    'tempRecord': str(read_temp())
}

req = Request(url)
req.add_header('Content-Type','application/json')
data = json.dumps(postdata)

response = urlopen(req,data)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3 urllib produces TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760728/python-3-urllib-produces-typeerror-post-data-should-be-bytes-or-an-iterable-of)

Comment: `response = urlopen(req,postdata)` works?

Comment: No, this works:
*response = urlopen(req, data.encode())*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
response = urlopen(req, data.encode())
```

Why?

Because `json.dump(postdata)` returns a str object,

whereas `urlopen` expects a `bytes` object.

So you have to convert `data` from `str` to `bytes`, and you do this using `encode`.

Comment: It works thank you :)
But can you told me how can i see the value of the temperature with that code? because i copied it and still dont know how.
Thanks alot.

Comment: First of all, if you find my answer helpful, you should accept the answer by clicking the 'V' sign next to it. Regarding the temp, I don't even know which URL you are trying to POST... you should add some more info

Comment: @ChawkiZouari try `data = response.read()`  and `print(data)`. Or if you have `JSON`  then `data =  json.loads( response.read() )` and then you can search in `data`

Comment: [Link](http://prntscr.com/nj2swt)
It shows me like that, can anyone knows how to fix this please?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really understand what you are trying to do here. If you are trying to read information from a web sensor, you should give some more information, for example, what is the URL of the sensor? Which model is that? etc...

Comment: I am using the DS18B20 sensor and i want to read the temperature with firebase with the code. Here is some information about the code:
[code](http://prntscr.com/nj3t8m)
Is it possible? Thanks.